# python logging using filename and line number

Tags: python, logging

I'm using the basic logging python module to add log.

I decide to create a log class, as follow, named `Log.py` :

```
class Log:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.LOGGER = logging.getLogger('Open-Capture')
        if self.LOGGER.hasHandlers():
            self.LOGGER.handlers.clear() # Clear the handlers to avoid double logs
        logFile = RotatingFileHandler(path, mode='a', maxBytes=5 * 1024 * 1024,
                            backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=0)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(threadName)-14s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)-15s] %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        logFile.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.LOGGER.addHandler(logFile)
        self.LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def info(self, msg):
        self.LOGGER.info(msg)

    def error(self, msg):
        self.LOGGER.error(msg)
```

As you can see, I have the `%(filename)s:%(lineno)` vars to add more lisibility. But in my log file I have `Log.py:34` instead of filename and line number of the source file because when I log I call it like this :

```
Log = Log(Config.cfg['GLOBAL']['logfile'])
Log.info('test log')
```

Is there any way to had the source file on my log file instead of `Log.py` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats your file name?

Comment: There are multiple python file using the Log class. `FindContact.py`, `FindDate.py` etc....

Comment: Is there not a file named Log.py?

Comment: I edit my post. The filename of Log class is `Log.py`

Comment: I'm confused because it's working as how it should. What do you mean by "But in my log file I have Log.py:34 instead of filename and line number" isn't Log.py is your filename and 34 is the line number?

Comment: Yes it is. I understand it works correctly for now. But instead of `Log.py:34` I want, for exemple : `FindContact.py:81` because on my FindContact.py file, line 81 I have : `Log.info('Find URL : ' + url.group())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, althrough I'm quite sure the implementation I'm posting here is not 100% safe and sure there is a better / more elegant implementation, take this as a hint.

To get the filename and line# of the caller you can use the `inspect` module, to add those custom infos to your logs you can add a custom `Filter`:

## log.py

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from inspect import getframeinfo, stack


class CallerFilter(logging.Filter):
    """ This class adds some context to the log record instance """
    file = ''
    line_n = ''

    def filter(self, record):
        record.file = self.file
        record.line_n = self.line_n
        return True

def caller_reader(f):
    """This wrapper updates the context with the callor infos"""
    def wrapper(self, *args):
        caller = getframeinfo(stack()[1][0])
        self._filter.file = caller.filename
        self._filter.line_n = caller.lineno
        return f(self, *args)
    return wrapper

class Log:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.LOGGER = logging.getLogger('Open-Capture')
        if self.LOGGER.hasHandlers():
            self.LOGGER.handlers.clear() # Clear the handlers to avoid double logs
        logFile = RotatingFileHandler(path, mode='a', maxBytes=5 * 1024 * 1024,
                            backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=0)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(threadName)-14s] [%(file)s:%(line_n)-15s] %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        logFile.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.LOGGER.addHandler(logFile)
        # Here we add the Filter, think of it as a context
        self._filter = CallerFilter()
        self.LOGGER.addFilter(self._filter)
        self.LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    @caller_reader
    def info(self, msg):
        self.LOGGER.info(msg)

    @caller_reader
    def error(self, msg):
        self.LOGGER.error(msg)
```

## script_file.py

```
from log import Log

log = Log('l.log')
log.info('LOG MESSAGE')
log.error('LOG MESSAGE 2 ')
log.info('LOG MESSAGE 2 ')
```

output:

```
[MainThread    ] [script_file.py:4              ] 17-01-2020 16:34:36 INFO LOG MESSAGE
[MainThread    ] [script_file.py:5              ] 17-01-2020 16:34:36 ERROR LOG MESSAGE 2
[MainThread    ] [script_file.py:6              ] 17-01-2020 16:34:36 INFO LOG MESSAGE 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well. But, why this isn't safe ?

Comment: Each call to the log "debug" and "error" methods I am storing the caller on CallerFilter class attributes, which are shared between different logger instances. This is safe for "normal" code, but say you are using this in a web app, there may be concurrency problems (depending on the app structure) that will lead to a log written with filename and number of a concurrent request... This is just theory though, if you use this on a script with no use of concurrency you'd be allright. (maybe better add a reset of "_filter" attributes after the call, now that I think about it... )

Comment: So if I use `logger.filters.clear()` at each Log Class call, before adding filter, it could be better ?

Comment: Yes, I guess so.

Comment: Great solution!